# The number of repetitions of a word in a txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, file, count, txt

I want count The number of repetitions of a word in a txt in Python
This is my code

```
    f=open('D:/hi.txt','r')
    f.read()
    h=input('enter a word:')
    def file()
        if h in f:
            Print(f.count)
```

Comment: Did you try running that code? What happened?

Comment: It only takes the word

Comment: Not quite right. That code has a syntax error as well as a reference to a non-existent function. Even if the function was defined correctly, you never [try to] call it

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('D:/hi.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()

h = input('enter a word:')

words = content.lower().split()

print(words.count(h))
```

Explanation: this reads the file `D:/hi.txt` into a string `content`, then separates the words into a list `words` (assuming you do not care about capitalization here) and then simply counts how often the inputted word `h` occurs in `words`.